# Node js send an email with pdf as attachement synchronously

Tags: node.js

Task : Get query from database => generate multiple pdf => send in mail attachment via node js
Problem: the problem here is before pdfs are generated my sendMail() function    called. So how to call sendMail function only after all pdfs generated?

```
pdfs = [];

// Pdf generate code
var generatePdf = function (rows) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            html = ejs.renderFile(
                'views/voucher.ejs',
                {
                    voucher: rows[i]
                },
                function (error, success) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        var pdf_path = '/srv/  voucher/uploads/voucher/' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + '.pdf';

                        htmlToPdf.convertHTMLString(success, pdf_path,     function (error, success) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log('Oh noes! Errorz!');
                                console.log(error);
                            } else {
                                pdfs.push(pdf_path);
                                console.log("Single");
                                console.log(pdfs);
                                console.log('Woot! Success!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            resolve();
    });
}

// send mail code
var sendMail = function () {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        console.log("All" + pdfs);
        pdfs.forEach(function (value, key) {
            // mail sending code
        });
    });
};


var findVoucherAndSendMail = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var query = con.query('SELECT * FROM voucher limit 20', function selectAll(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            resolve(rows);

        });

    });
};

findVoucherAndSendMail().then(function (fromResolve) {
    return generatePdf(fromResolve);
}).then(function () {
    return sendMail();
}).catch(function () {
});
```

Comment: It will not solve your problem but you don't return the promise in sendMail

Comment: I tested your code and can't reproduce your issue. Are you sure that sendMail is called before ?

Comment: yes, i haven't write my pdf generation code in generate pdf function it takes around 3 to 5 seconds so sendmail is called before pdf generation.

Comment: You should have write your pdf generation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is link to an asynchronous behavior in your for loop when generating pdf.
Your promise is resolved before your pdfs are generated.
You should use `Promise.all` to wait for generation completion.

```
function generatePdf(rows) {
  return Promise.all(rows.map(row => asyncPdfGeneration(row));
}

function asyncPdfGeneration(row) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...generate pdf
    resolve(pdf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd 'then' is on your function findVoucherAndSendMail(), so both generatePdf() and sendMail() will fire once findVoucherAndSendMail() is finished.

Place the 2nd 'then' on generatePdf()

```
findVoucherAndSendMail().then(function (fromResolve) {
    return generatePdf(fromResolve).then(function () {
         return sendMail();
     });
}).catch(function () {
});
```

*edit*

Did you try: `resolve(pdfs);` instead of just `resolve();`

Comment: Not really... You can and should chain promises to avoid callback hell

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine Understood. However this should solve his immediate problem considering he doesn't know much about Promises.